# Filter an Array of Dictionaries by using a Predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, nsarray, nspredicate

I have the following array of dictionaries:

```
Printing description of newOrderbookBids:
<__NSArrayI 0x10053e7c0>(
{
    price = "10.14";
    size = 148;
},
{
    price = "10.134";
    size = 0;
},
{
    price = "10.131";
    size = 321;
})
```

Each dictionary in the array has the keys `price` and `size`, both are numbers.

I would like to return a filtered array which contains only the dictionaries for which `size > 0`. In this example, this would be the array with dictionary #1 and #3, but without dictionary #2:

```
   ({
        price = "10.14";
        size = 148;
    },
    {
        price = "10.131";
        size = 321;
    })
```

I have tried the following code snippet to filter my `NSArray *newOrderbookBids` by size:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size > 0"];
newOrderbookBids = [newOrderbookBids filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Unfortunately my code crashes with the runtime error

```
[NSSymbolicExpression compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxx
```

What is wrong with my code and predicate?
How can I filter by `size > 0`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SIZE" is a reserved keyword in the ["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)
and the keywords are case-insensitive.

To solve that problem, use the "%K" format argument as a var arg substitution for a 
*key path*:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > 0", @"size"];
```

Comment: Perfect! This is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Reserved Words

The following words are reserved:

AND, OR, IN, NOT, ALL, ANY, SOME, NONE, LIKE, CASEINSENSITIVE, CI, MATCHES, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH, BETWEEN, NULL, NIL, SELF, TRUE, YES, FALSE, NO, FIRST, LAST, SIZE, ANYKEY, SUBQUERY, CAST, TRUEPREDICATE, FALSEPREDICATE

A clearer error message when this happens would be nice.

Comment: I agree with you that the error message is very misleading. Thank you for the list of reserved words. Never thought about this being the error.

Comment: I remember tearing my hair out over this a while back. I'm sure FIRST, LAST and SIZE collide with people's data models all the time.